# what is best way to copy 100GB data between two AWS volumes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two volumes attached to the same instance and it is taking 5 hours to transfer 100GB from one to the other using linux mv.

The c5.large instance supposedly uses enhanced network architecture and has a network speed of .74 Gigabits/s = .0925 Gigabytes per second. So I was expecting .74/8*60*60=333GB per hour. I am 15 times slower.

Where did I go wrong? Is there a better solution?

Comment: Can you see from the monitoring where the bottleneck is, is it purely data transfer, or is another metric?

Comment: I am just doing "watch df" and looking at the %used on the new volume. I have no other applications running. I was using the standard gp2 volumes so maybe that is it? I have just increased to provisioned iops with 10 times the speed. Not speeded up though.

Comment: Also I note there is a status warning "I/O throughput (0 to 50%) is well below expectations". Not sure what I am supposed to do about it. Aren't AWS supposed to deliver that?

Comment: if it's one time activity, try zipping the file first and then transferring. Otherwise investigate more to find the bottleneck first.

Comment: You have to look at the EBS Bandwidth allocated to the instance, not the regular network bandwidth. C5.xlarge has *up to* 3500mbps EBS throughput. Since you are reading from one EBS volume and writing to another, you would need to reduce that throughput by half to see your possible maximum speed, and even then that's not guaranteed. Also you need to check the maximum IOPS of the two EBS volumes. If they have low IOPS you aren't going to get a good transfer rate. You need to look at the IOPS charts on both volumes in CloudWatch to see if that is the bottleneck.

Comment: OK am now seeing an increase in speed to 30mbps. iops have reached 2000 versus the 3000 allowed on each volume. However this is a long way from maximum bandwith of 3500mbps which I understand should be possible for 30 minutes; or even from maximum throughput of 437mbps.

Comment: And it keeps getting exponentially faster! I guess just needed time to warm up or fill some buffers or something.

Comment: @simon did you recently create either volume from a snapshot?

Comment: The instance volume was launched from an image based on snapshot. The empty volume was created from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I use c.large instances and the speed is *up to* .74 Gigabits/s in practice e.g. downloading from S3 buckets, is about .45MBits/s which is more than an order of magnitude less than that nominal value (for a c4.xlarge node)

I suggest you chop your data into 1GB packages and use the following script to download them onto the attached storage option of your choice.

```
for i in {part001..part100}
  do
    echo " $i Download"
    fnam=$i.csv.bz2
    wget -O /tmp/data/$fnam http://address/to/the/data/$fnam
    echo "$(date) $i Unzip"
    bunzip2 /tmp/data/$fnam
  done
```